# How to create a file by getting the filename from the user in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to create a file by getting the filename from the user in javascript?

Comment: This question cannot be usefully answered in its current form. Create a file on a client system from a web browser? Create a file on a server? As part of a shell script?

Answer (score 1):

Since javascript is a client-side language, you cannot create a file on the server using javascript alone. Probably the best thing to do is POST the variable with the filename to a PHP file.

Comment: JavaScript is not a client-side language. JavaScript is a language. The most common (by far) deployment of it is in web browsers, but that doesn't make it a client-side language. I use JavaScript for server-side scripting all the time, as well as for shell scripts.

Comment: @T.J. I have been thinking of using JavaScript on the server too via Aptana Jaxer. Which web server and JavaScript engine do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Some more information might prove helpful, but if I take your question at face value the answer is "You can't".

Javascript run in the browser from a website (the most common way) has no access to the desktop and can't create a file on it.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing here that you want to use ?